# Cannot modify Desktops in Rad Studio 11.1

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

I am running Windows 11 and I have Rad Studio 11.1 installed.  Since 11.1 I am unable to save my desktop.  Has anyone else seen this and does anyone know of a work round?  It seems to me that the application is not reading or writing to the .dst files.  I modified the width and client width in Default Layout.dst using Notepad++ but when I opened Rad Studio the size was unchanged.  When I closed Rad Studio the dst file was not saved.

I have Save Project Desktop on closing enabled.

Comment: Just file a bug report.

Comment: What your are looking for should be in the ``project.dsk``, not in project.dst. At least for the option setting you mentioned. The desktop settings can be stored using the view menu, in a subsection about desktops.

Comment: @DelphiCoder, since a while the desktop layouts of Delphi are indeed stored in dst files. Unfortunately the description is not clear enough to spot the cause of the problem.

Comment: In which location do you expect the dst file to be?

Comment: @Uwe Raabe C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\22.0\Default Layout.dst

Comment: Can you give a explain exactly what you changed, what you expect and what happened.

Comment: @UweRaabe  I changed the Width and Client width in the Main Window section.  Tried increasing and decreasing but Rad Studio still came back the same size.  Just to confirm, closed Rad Studio altered and save the DST file and restarted Rad Studio

Comment: I've reported issue to Embarcadero

Comment: Are you aware that these values are not absolute but in 1/100th percent? F.i. Width=5000 means 50% of the parents width (whatever that parent actually is). If you give impossible values the IDE will probably ignore them.

Comment: @UweRaabe I think it is a scaling issue., each time I switch between Default layout and Debug Layout the Application gets progressively smaller.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by launching the "DPI Unaware" version

Comment: RAd Studio was set up as Low DPI (96).  Tried it on Automatic (Screen DPI) but no difference.